# What is the expected behavior of material design wave effect?

Tags: html, css, material-design, css-transitions, materialize

I have been reading the [ripple/waves effect in Material Design](http://materializecss.com/waves.html). What I observed is that if while pressing continually near the right end of the green wave button, if I suddenly start pressing continually near the left end, then the button goes completely white and never retreat to its original green color.

My question is, is this the expected behavior as per Material Design guidelines or a bug? Tkx!

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior. Why would you want the wave to retreat?

Comment: @zessx Because if I don't press at the opposite end the color retreat back to green.

Comment: I think this is a bug but you'd really have to ask Google about it. If you do this, and then mouse in and out a couple times, it will incrementally return to its default green color. Seems like an odd behavior choice either way.

Comment: @TylerH How should I reach them out? Shall I report this on git repo of material css?

Comment: Yes that's probably a good place to start.